# Android camera2: what kind of upsampling/downsampling is done to fit my streams?

Tags: android, image, camera

I want to get image flows with the least distortions possible(no noise reduction, etc) without having to deal with RAW outputs.
I'm working with two streams(one when using the deprecated `camera`), one for the preview and one for the processing. I understand the camera2 api, but am wondering what kind of upsampling/downsampling is used when fitting the sensor output to the surfaces?

More specifically, I'm working on zoomed images, and according to the camera2 documentation concerning [cropping](https://source.android.com/devices/camera/camera3_crop_reprocess.html#) and the [references](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#SCALER_CROP_REGION):

> For non-raw streams, any additional per-stream cropping will be done to maximize the final pixel area of the stream.

The whole concept is easy enough to understand, but it's also mentioned that:

> Output streams use this rectangle to produce their output, cropping to a smaller region if necessary to maintain the stream's aspect ratio, then scaling the sensor input to match the output's configured resolution.

But I haven't been able to find any info about this scaling. Which method is used(filter based, bicubic, edge-directed, etc)? is there a way to get this info? and is there a way I can actually choose which one is used?

Concerning the deprecated `camera`, I'm guessing the zoom is just simpler, in the sense that it's probably equivalent to having `SCALER_CROPPING_TYPE_CENTER_ONLY` with only a limited set of crop regions corresponding to the exposed zoom ratios. But is the image scaling the same as in `camera2`?  If someone could shed some light I'd be happy.

---

## Real life example

Camera sensor: 5312x2988(16:9)

I want a 4x zoom so the crop region should be (1992, 1120, 1328, 747)
(btw what happens to odd sizes? for instance with `SCALER_CROPPING_TYPE_CENTER_ONLY` devices?)

Now I have a surface of size(1920, 1080), the crop area and the stream ratio fit, but the 1328x747 values must be transformed to fill the 1920x1080 surface. The nature of this transformation is what I want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scaling algorithm used depends on the device; generally for power efficiency and speed, scaling is done in hardware blocks usually at the end of camera image signal processor (ISP) pipeline.

Therefore, you can't generally rely on it being any particular kind of scaling or filtering.  Unfortunately, if you want to understand the entire processing pipeline, you have to start with RAW and implement it yourself.

If you're on the same device, the old camera API and the new camera2 API talk to the same hardware abstraction layer, and the same hardware scalers, so the scaling output will generally match exactly for the same resolution. (with the exception of LEGACY-level devices, where camera2 may need additional GPU-based scaling, which will be bilinear downsampling - but you don't really know when this would apply).

Comment: I didn't have high hopes of having someone actually answering my question and wasn't expecting the scaling method to be published or documented, but then you never know.... So thanks for taking the time and for confirming my thoughts.